# How to examine the change of event sequences

Tags: time-series, categorical-data

Let's assume we have a sequence of events $x_1, x_2, ...,x_n$ and each event can be described as a categorical variable from domain $\{A, B, C...\}$. The time interval between two consecutive events is not fixed.

An example could be a researcher's publication record. Each publication is an event and the domain is the set of all fields, {Statistics, Data Mining, ...}. Of course, the time interval between two consecutive publications is not fixed.

My question is, are there any math/stat/data mining/.. tools to analyze these kind of data, so we could answer following questions?

- **Given a sequence, we can tell whether there is a significant change in the value of events**. For example, in the beginning, the researcher's publications are mostly about statistics, and for some reasons the interest has changed and more machine learning papers are published.
- **Given a group of sequences, we can tell whether there is a significant change in the value of events in many of them**. I guess the answer of this question is based on the answer of first question.
- **Given a sequence, we can tell whether there is a significant change in the time interval**. For example, a researcher publishes 1 article per month in the beginning, but publishes 1 article per year after he got tenure:)
- **And there may be more questions....**

A simple method is to draw a timeline chart for each sequence. But it would not be acceptable if we want to draw sound conclusions from the data.